# Is it possible to make an association between a Table and View in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I have 2 databases (sql server 2005) in my system, one for configuration data and the other one for Application Data, but there are some tables that are needed in both databases. We've solved that using Synonyms but the problem is when we map the tables in Entity Framework.
We have a Language table in the config database, used for localization purposes. But in the application we have a table called "Countries", and it has a child table to contain the country's fields translated.
My Entity Framework Context maps tables in the Application database and the only way to map the Languages table from the other database is including a View created in the Application Database. Everything works fine, but when I try to make an Association between the CountryTranslation entity and the Language entity I get this exception:

```
Problem in Mapping Fragments starting at lines 733, 855: Non-Primary-Key column(s) [pai_codlan] are being mapped in both fragments to different conceptual side properties - data inconsistency is possible because the corresponding conceptual side properties can be independently modified.
```

Do you know if this is a possible scenario? How do I resolve this?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
All I had to do was delete the column that was mapped as a Entity Property and just keep the Navigational Property..

Comment: FYI, you can go ahead and mark your own answer as the answer.